# I can not run first app on android studio

Tags: android-studio

I installed Android Studio , but I can not run first app.

Of course, I downloaded jdk before, and then I created a new variable named JAVA_HOME ,assigned the value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin,
and also add this to Path (using ; ).

Then I downloaded Android Stdio and installed it  , intending to create my first app. But I get nothing but a blank screen with no option for running  , and no simulator.

Moreover, I can see that it's syncing forever...

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some image in order to see what is happening to you...